# Relation between spherical harmonics in $\mathbb{S}^2$ vs circular harmonics in $\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to better understand how a function on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ can be decomposed in terms of spherical harmonics. In particular I have found this notation, given that $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then we can write:

$$f(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^la_m^lY_m^l(\textbf{x}) \, ,$$

where the family of functions $Y_m^l : \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{S}^2)$. I'm more familiar with the notion of Fourier Transform, where we have a basis of complex exponentials $\{e^{ilx}\}_{l \in \mathbb{Z}}$ that allow to describe any periodic function as weighted sum of sines/cosines in the following way:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}f_n e^{inx}$$

with $f_n$ being the Fourier coefficients. So I'm trying to relate this second statement to the first one, in particular I'm a bit confused about why do we have two sum operators on the first one, and the precise role of the indexes $l$ and $m$.

Comment: The $l$ specifies which eigenspace of the Laplacian we are in, and $m$ is just there to label our orthonormal eigenbasis function of our $2l+1$-dimensional vector space.  You get a nicer description when you think in terms of the corresponding harmonic polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($l$ is the total degree (after taking out $x^2+y^2+z^2$ factors), $|m|$ is the degrees in $x,y$ only exactly like $e^{im\theta}$ for $S^1$ in $xy$-plane).  The exact nature of the sign of $m$ depends whether you are talking the real or complex version of $Y_{lm}$.